# VBA Vlookup value same as first row

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, vlookup

I'm trying to use `vlookup()` function under for loop condition, but the value only follow only the first row value. This is my code. Sorry, the code is quite messy; I'm still learning VBA.

```
Sub vlookup_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim result As String
Dim i As Long
Dim iLast As Long
Dim result1 As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim WrkSht As String
WrkSht = "Sheet1"
iLast = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("InventoryReport")


For i = 10 To iLast
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sheet.Range("$B$10"), _ 
            sheet1.Range("$B$10:$Q$48"), 16, False)
    Sheets(WrkSht).Cells(i, 9).Value = result
Next i

End Sub
```

Below picture shows the result.Any idea to solve this?

Expected and Current Result:
[image: Expected and Current Result]

Comment: I think you are using the wrong approach with `vlookup()`. But I am having an issue understanding exactly what you are wanting here. Which values are you trying to look up? Your `itemRow` and `i` are redundant btw.

Comment: Thank you. i have edited my code and remove the redundant one. I want to look up the value from another sheet under Q column. By comparing the value from this sheet under column C and another sheet also under column. @K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Comment: btw, I just wanted to clarify my previous statement. When I said "wrong approach" with vlookup, I meant in VBA. But I am now trying to figure out why you are needing VBA at all. Are you against just using vlookup as a normal formula?

Comment: Sorry, because the value from another sheet is keep updating because it is linked to the SQL. so each time I click the update button. it will automatically update value form that sheet and this sheet too.

Comment: Okay, and the next issue is that you have 9 values of `NG7074600` in column B. How should excel know which one you are wanting to match on the other sheet? Or would the return results be the exact same for each one?

Comment: Yes. It will return the exact same for each one. @K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Comment: One last question (well two)... #1) What column in sheet 2 matches column B? ___ #2) What column on sheet2 is the value you want to bring back to column I on sheet1?  I am conffused because your formula says B, but your question says C.

Comment: Im sorry again. 1) It is column B. 2) it is under column Q. @K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's consider dumping the `VLOOKUP()` option. We are using VBA, so we have more power when it comes to looking up ranges.

I think we should go with using the `range.Find()` method here. Set this object, use the `Row()` property to match the Q column on that range, and return it to your I column in ws1.

Try this

```
Sub vlookup_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim iLast As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim findRng As Range

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InventoryReport")

    'Changed ActiveWorksheet to ws1 for your iLast
    iLast = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 10 To iLast

        Set findRng = ws2.Range("B:B").Find(ws1.Cells(i, "B"), , xlValues, xlWhole)

        If Not findRng Is Nothing Then
            ws1.Cells(i, "I") = ws2.Cells(findRng.Row, "Q")
        Else
            ws1.Cells(i, "I") = 0
        End If

        Set findRng = Nothing

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. and sorry for troubling you. I need to study your code and fully understand it. :D

Comment: You're not troubling me at all. If I didn't enjoy helping then I wouldn't be here :D

Comment: 1 more question, what if the value doesn't exist from ws2? From your code, it does return value. but actually, it should return 0.

Comment: It shouldn't return any value atm. That's the point of the `If Not findRng Is Nothing Then`. I will modify it, one moment

Comment: Okay. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 0):

I see you use the excel worksheet function, but use the form of formulaR1C1 will be better. And record the Macro will free you from calculate the row# for the formula.
how to do:
You can just video this operation to get that code in your excel by click Tab "Developer" in your 
excel/"record Macro" then input the formular in the cell then "stop recording" then Alt+F11 to get to
access the code of the vlookup formula:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R10C2,R[3]C[-1]:R[41]C[11],16,0)"
```